Partitioning the Distribution database in a MSSQL Transactional Replication environment
I was wondering if anyone has tried to partition the Distribution system database on the Distributor, to see if it is beneficial for the replication.
In a highly transactional environment, we have 4 databases residing on the same Publisher, being replicated to a remote Subscriber with pull subscriptions. The Distributor is on the Subscriber instance, but this is not obligatory.
We experience a lot of blocking where the blocked process is Repl-LogReader-db1 job trying to write to the Distribution database, and the blocking process is the Repl-LogReader-db2 job that is writing on the Distribution database.
Unfortunately, we cannot use separate distribution databases, as the Publisher for both db1 and db2 is the same.
So, I was wondering if we could have in the Distribution database specific tables, such as MSrepl_transactions & MSrepl_commands, partitioned by publisher_database_id.
Most probably not, but before I try on a dev environment I thought I shared my thoughts.

You can try, but it is absolutely unsupported and has never been tested.

To add to @SeanGallardy comment, IF it works, it will probably break installation of Cumulative Updates touching the distribution database.

It is definitely unsupported, but it is challenging :)

I'm addition to what Sean said, I'm highly suspect that you'll find any benefit in doing so. Out of curiosity, what does "highly transactional' mean to you?
